# Getting WebSocket to work from Remote URL

Tags: php, html, websocket

I recently set up a WebSocket server on one of my home machines and am trying to get it to work from a remote connection. I used the following PHP WebSocket solution (supports Draft 75 and 76):

Niko Kaiser's PHP Websocket Server

From a local connection the demo works flawlessly. I can use the client-side demo just fine from localhost, my DNS pointed at my home machine, and (the weirdest part) a remote PHP host that hosts ONLY the client file. The javascript points back to my home machine for the WebSocket.

The problem happens when I use another machine, something not based at home. Even when I go to the exact same URL, the WebSocket will not connect. So here is what is happening:

URL pointing to home machine - Works from home only. Page loads from other PCs but WebSocket wont connect.
http://whoisryannystrom.com/tests/socket/client - Works from home only. Page loads from other PCs but WebSocket wont connect.

I have the WebSocket address in the client.html file set up like this (which I know is correct). This is the same in the localhost and remote client html file.

```
var server = new WebPush('ws://rnystrom.mine.nu:8000/echo');
```

Then I get a little confused as to what addresses the server's PHP files need to have. Here is what I have currently:

The main server php (server.php):

```
$server = new \WebSocket\Server('rnystrom.mine.nu', 8000);
```

And then in the \server\lib\WebSocket (the WebSocket class files, I think...) I use 'localhost'. I've tried 'rnystrom.mine.nu' and 'localhost', both work on the home machine and none of them work remotely, so it doesn't seem to make a difference. I believe that $host is used in the constructor or something. The main server.php defines what $host is.

I'm at a loss. All I really want to do is to be able to begin experimenting with WebSockets, but I can't even start if I can't connect remotely! It's no fun to have to remote desktop every time I want to edit or see my work!

Answer (score 4):

I noticed this is old but I had this problem at one point. Make it bind to 0.0.0.0 as this makes it listen on all (for lack of a better word) hosts.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your firewall is configured to allow external connections on port 80, but not on port 8000.